Calculating return time in random proccess
how can we calculate the time that a random process $h(t)$ with mean $\mu$  and variance $\text{Var}_h$ to return to its mean ($\mu$)  after being less than $\mu$ ?

What do you mean with "return to its mean"? A random process does not ever necessarily take its mean value. For example, take the rolling of six-sided dice: the expectation of that process is 3.5, at any point in time, but the value 3.5 is never actually achieved, because the die has no side with 3 and a half dots on it. You find the same in semiconductor physics with charge carrier energies, with photons, and a lot of other cases.

@Marcus Müller It might make sense if "return to its mean" is understood as stipulation leading to a conditional expectation where a non-trivial condition is restricting (constraining) long-term mean/variance values over realizations. Under this stipulation, the values can become time-varying. Notice also "after being less than μ" in the OP question. Still, it seems that the question pertains to the math/statistics, rather than DSP, realm.

Thank you Marcus,
In fact I mean how we can calculate the time it takes for the process to go from a value less than \mu to \mu.
In some references it called the ``hitting time'' or ''relaxation time''

@alinouruzi you seem to have a very specific class of random processes in mind. Generally, you can't calculate such a time – the process is random after all – and you might only be able to calculate an expectation of a time that a specifically defined random process takes. As V.V.T says, you will have to write down a signal for us here – please really define the random process you mean. In general, random processes simply don't "do" what you want to calculate, so we can't help you.

(your question is fully unclear without you defining your random process in terms as mathematical as you can – we'll gladly help if you can guide the way. But my example still holds: how do you calculate the time that it takes a fair die to roll a number at least 3.5? You can't calculate that. You can make a stochastic statement, maybe about the expectation of that time, or a quartile, if you know enough about the process you deal with. But in your question, there's absolutely no model for your stochastic process (aside from it having a Variance, and a mean))

Thank you for your feedback.

Yes.I explain more clear.

@alinouruzi any news on a definition?

Thank you.
Assume that we have a random process
$h(t)$
that follows Rayleigh ($\sigma^{2}$). Considering that now the value of $h$ is less than $h_{th}$.
On average, how long does it take for the amount of more than $h_{th}$ to appear?
And what is the maximum amount of this time?

@Marcus Müller
Dear Marcus I provide better definition here
